# Talend -Double type Division

Tags: java, division, talend

I am ashamed to ask this question Here.I have been bashing my head against the wall for like 4 hours now trying to figure out why in the world double Outpucol = 315.0/23.0; is telling me that answer is 315.0

We have talend tool uses java code.

**Input:**

in tmap component Output mapping field Expression is

```
Outputcol---->row1.inputcol=="CS"?Double.valueOf(Var.Var3)/Double.valueOf(Var.Var5):Double.valueOf(Var.Var3)
```

**Symptom :** when running the job not getting any error on execution. But at the same time not getting desired output of division of double.

**We also tried**

```
firstdouble.divide(secondDouble)
```

method of talend. But it did not work for me.

Is there a alternate way or possible workaround for such values division?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try doing `row1.inputcol.equals("CS")`

Comment: You compare strings using ==, which will always return false. Then in goes to Double.valueOf(Var.Var3), which results in your first argument to be returned.

Comment: Thanks  i WILL use row1.inputcol.equals("CS").  and  will try to implement your words in system. will get back to you.

Comment: I prefer `equalsIgnoreCase()` over `equals()`.

Comment: Glad it looks precise. I will replace by